# Как сделать адаптивный background c двумя фото?

Tags: html, css

[В этом макете](https://www.behance.net/gallery/33742162/WOODER-Free-PSD-Template) верхняя часть с background из двух фото, как их склеить ? нужно чтобы была адаптивность и они не растягивались на маленьком экране
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.blockimg{
 background: url("img/d2.png"),
 url("img/1d.png");
 position: relative;
 background-position:left -20px, right;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-color: #444;
 background-size: 1049px 1001px , 903px 1043px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 

 box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 25px;
 width:100%;
 min-height: 1043px;
 border-style: solid;
border-color: #cacd58;
border-width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: не совсем понятно как должно выглядеть

Comment: как на макете должно выглядеть

Comment: макет - это первая картинка или вторая?

Comment: конечно первая. вторая это то что у меня сейчас получается, при уменьшении в браузере до 30%, потому что на 100% первое фото перекрывает второе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, использовать псевдоэлементы у `body`, сделать им абсолютное позиционирование, ширину в половину экрана и разные фоны.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 200vh;
}

body::before,
body::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 50vw;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

body::before {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.trinixy.ru/pics3/20080124/podb/6/krasota_01.jpg');
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

body::after {
  background-image: url('https://kolyan.net/uploads/posts/2012-11/thumbs/1353432941_best-full-hd-wallpapers-32-39.jpg');
  right: 0;
  height: 105vh;
}

body > * {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<h1>Example</h1>
```

---

Но я бы сделал единую картинку, по той причине, что она загрузится быстрее.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 105vh;
  background: #444 url('https://i.imgur.com/r61XFBx.png') no-repeat top center / cover;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: в первом варианте можно сделать затемнение как на макете ?

Comment: @Anrisssss, через что делается? Если через `filter`, то да.

Comment: я вот так сделал, но в старом эксплоллере не работает к сожалению  body::after {
 background-image:  url("img/1d.png");
 right: 0;
 height: 105vh;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.719);
    background-blend-mode: darken;
    color: white;
  }

Comment: @Anrisssss, ie надо отправлять на помойку, он даже "новый" не умеет  работать с [background-blend-mode](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode). Проще это затемнение в графическом редакторе сделать, тогда будет работать.